# Storing the data on firebase Realtime Database does not

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Note: I'm a beginner in Firebase and this question may be a  duplicate.

I'm trying to store data in the Firebase Realtime database but data does not store this is a database Rule.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

This is code:

```
import {ref,set, getDatabase } from 'firebase/database';
function handleAddCartItemSave(product) {
        const db = getDatabase();
        const uid = selectorLogin.uid;

        set(ref(db, '/cart'),  { 
            product, 
            uid,
        });
        console.log(uid, product);
    }
```

What is a mistake in the above code?

Comment: "data does not store" is hard to help with. Can you show how your `product` and `selectorLogin` are initialized? Or even better: can you reproduce the problem when you hard-code those values?

Comment: my FirebaseConfig inside does not mention in database URL, then add the database: URL, it store the data on firebase Thanks for helping @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: The title appears to be missing some words, and thus this question is rather confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this.

```
const db = getDatabase();
const ref = db.ref('/cart');
ref.set({
    product: product,
    uid : uid
})
```

Comment: i'm using your style it throws ref is not a function

Comment: Change the reference to your own db child reference.

Comment: const ref = db.ref('/cart'); <- here throw the error ref is not a function

Comment: @UzzamAltaf You are mixing the syntax for the v8 and v9 SDKs in your answer here, which won't work. Since you do `const db = getDatabase()`, getting a reference from that is done with `const ref = ref(db, 'cart')`. But at that point I don't see how your code does anything different from what NgSharma is doing already. Can you elaborate how your change would address their problem?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen basically I want to save data in firebase, but data is not kept in firebase and Even then I follow the firebase documentation, above is my code

Answer (score 0):

Setting overrides data at that specific location, if you want to store multiple cart objects I would recommend using push here. Looks like you are using the v9 api syntax,

[Based on their documentation found here:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)

**First make sure you've properly initialized the web sdk in your project with the provided firebase credentials** [Read more about this here:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#register-app)

Then you can push/set information as follows below:

```
import { getDatabase, ref, push, set } from "firebase/database";

// Create a new post reference with an auto-generated id
const db = getDatabase();
const uid = selectorLogin.uid;
const cartRef = ref(db, 'cart/');
const newCartRef = push(cartRef);
set(newCartRef, {
    product, 
    uid,
});
```

**Things to check**

- Check that the firebase app was initialized properly
- Double check that the values you are trying to store are initialized and not undefined,
- You should push to a new reference inside cart, although may not be what you intend. If this is **not** what you intend, there are still other suggestions in this answer that may assist.

Comment: it is possible to store where **newCartRef** replace with **uid** for Example :
set(uid, { products }); **products is array**

Comment: @NgSharma Yea instead of pushing a ref, using push(), create the cart ref as follows: const cartRef = ref(db, `cart/${uid}`), then set(cartRef, {products}) assuming products is a variable name with an array as the value.

Comment: make sure the above cart/${uid} is in a js template string, stack overflow formatted it and I didn't escape it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: ref(database, 'cart/'`${uid}`); This statement throw error  **TypeError: "cart/" is not a function**

Comment: The whole thing needs to be a template string, `const cartRef = ref(database, \`cart/${uid}\`)` assuming you are able to work with es6+